# In jQuery or JavaScript, select child element adjoining the parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to select the child elements which are joined with the parent. For example, in the following HTML, I only want to select the child (`strong`) of the second and fourth paragraphs, since in those two cases the child & parent are adjoining (i.e. no text or markup between the child & parent elements):

```
<p>This is line <strong>number one</strong></p>
<p><strong>This is line number two</strong></p>
<p>This <strong>is line number three</strong></p>
<p><strong>This is line</strong> number four</p>
```

How can I do this with just the selectors if possible?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `filter` method:

```
$('p > strong').filter(function(){
   return !this.previousSibling;
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8GZ5k/)

Comment: Thanks for the concise solution.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I do this with just the selectors if possible?!

You can't, because selectors don't consider text nodes (only element nodes). You can get select all `p > strong` nodes and test whether the node is the first child of its parent:

```
$('p > strong').filter(function() {
    return this === this.parentNode.firstChild;
});
```

However, this only works if the parent really doesn't have any other node as first child, not even even a text node with only whitespaces. I.e. this method wouldn't select `strong` in the following case:

```
<p>
    <strong>This is line</strong> number four
</p>
```

If you want to ignore white space only text nodes, you can check whether the first child is such a node:

```
$('p > strong:nth-child(1)').filter(function() {
    var firstChild =  this.parentNode.firstChild;
    return firstChild === this ||
           firstChild.nodeName === 'TEXT' && !$.trim(firstChild.nodeValue);
});
```

To make the filter condition simpler, I used `strong:nth-child(1)`, which already will only select a `strong` element, if it is the first (element) child of its parent.